# PHP how to get month wise record from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I need your help. I have the following data in mysql, my requirement is to sum month wise amount.

```
Amount == Date
5000   || 01-05-2017 //Month May
6000   || 05-05-2017  //Month May
7000   || 20-05-2017  //Month May
10000  || 01-06-2017 //Month June
12000  || 05-06-2017  //Month June
13000  || 20-06-2017  //Month June
```

Expected  Result:

```
Sum = May 18000
Sum = June 35000
Sum = July 111111
```

Comment: have you tried anything? such as an aggregate mysql function? such as `SUM()`?

Comment: I tried sum but i dont know how get data montwise for ex: i select range from jan to march, it automaticaly sum the record month wise and show result.

Comment: so edit your question to show us what you tried, maybe you made an error somewhere

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `SUM` aggregation function with `GROUP BY` & [dateTime functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

```
SELECT
    SUM(AmountColumn),
    DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%M %Y') AS MONTH
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(record_date, '%M %Y')
```

Comment: He wants month by summation,Not month and year.

Comment: Month & year: both must be included in the GROUP BY so it won't sum same month of different years

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(AMOUNT),
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_COLUMN,'%M') 
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE_COLUMN,'%m')
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps.